# Random behavior of "command not found" in bash script that takes only part of the command

Tags: bash, random, command

I am facing a really strange problem on a Bash script, and would like to know if anyone already had this issue. 
My script basically throws random "command not found" errors on a particular line, but not always with the same "command". Here is an example:

```
    ./myscript.sh: line 193: e: command not found
    ./myscript.sh: line 194: iles: command not found
    ./myscript.sh: line 194: ge_files: command not found
```

And here are the incriminated lines

```
184 for SERVER in `echo $SERVERS` ; do
185 - 192 Do some stuff...
193 done
194 merge_files
```

(merge_files is a function that has been declared before in the script.)

So the issue seems to be that it splits up those lines from time to time? It really seems random as it does not always break, just sometimes (I guess something wrong in the input of the script? I'm parsing logs)

Has anyone ever faced this?

Comment: try to come up with the smallest possible script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: are you editing (and saving) the script while it's running?

Comment: turn on the shell debugging, i.e. `set -vx`, then you'll see the values of the variables. ALSO if your source for `$SERVERS` is from a file, is that file created on MSWindows/DOS? If so, use `dos2unix` to remove '^M\ chars that may be causing problems. Good luck.

Comment: Don't use `echo $SERVERS`, just plain `for SERVER in $SERVERS` is much clearer and exactly the same. As for the problem, do you have non-printables about?

Comment: Hi and thanks! I can't really figure out a smaller script to reproduce the issue for now. For glenn, I am indeed doing forced RSYNC fails (the script is about gathering rsync fails) by using CTRL+C. I'll try turning on the verbose mode shellter, thanks! And for Kevin, I'm not sure to have non printables, I'm trying to track them though. I'll let you guys know if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe any of your commands (ffmpeg?) reads from standard input which truncates the commands, so you see just part of it. Try to add `< /dev/null` to your commands to see if this is the problem

Comment: No, all my commands are pretty straightforward, calling other .sh scripts that themselves mostly to some "finds" to retrieve lists of files. I'll try the /dev/null thing though, thanks!